# Python: color Canadian provinces in a shapefile based on given values

Tags: python, shapefile, matplotlib, colormap

The goal here is to create a [choropleth map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) of Canada in Python. Suppose I have a dictionary with values referring to each Canadian province/territory:

```
values={'Alberta': 1.0,
 'British Columbia': 2.0,
 'Manitoba': 3.0,
 'New Brunswick': 4.0,
 'Newfoundland and Labrador': 5.0,
 'Northwest Territories': 6.0,
 'Nova Scotia': 7.0,
 'Nunavut': 8.0,
 'Ontario': 9.0,
 'Prince Edward Island': 10.0,
 'Quebec': 11.0,
 'Saskatchewan': 12.0,
 'Yukon': 13.0}
```

Now I want to color each province based on the corresponding value in `values`, using a continuous colormap (e.g., shades of red). **How to do that?**

So far I have only been able to plot the Canadian provinces/territory within matplotlib, but their shapes appear in a unique color, and I don't know how to change that according to the numbers in `values`.

This is where you can find the shapefile: http://www.filedropper.com/canadm1

And this is my code to date:

```
import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
#   -- input --
sf = shapefile.Reader("myfolder\CAN_adm1.shp")
recs    = sf.records()
shapes  = sf.shapes()
Nshp    = len(shapes)
cns     = []
for nshp in xrange(Nshp):
    cns.append(recs[nshp][1])
cns = array(cns)
cm    = get_cmap('Dark2')
cccol = cm(1.*arange(Nshp)/Nshp)
#   -- plot --
fig     = plt.figure()
ax      = fig.add_subplot(111)
for nshp in xrange(Nshp):
    ptchs   = []
    pts     = array(shapes[nshp].points)
    prt     = shapes[nshp].parts
    par     = list(prt) + [pts.shape[0]]
    for pij in xrange(len(prt)):
     ptchs.append(Polygon(pts[par[pij]:par[pij+1]]))
    ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(ptchs,facecolor=None,edgecolor='k', linewidths=.5))
ax.set_xlim(-160,-40)
ax.set_ylim(40,90)
```

This is the image I am getting so far:

[image]

Comment: [shapefile and matplotlib: plot polygon collection of shapefile coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15972203/835653)

Comment: Yes, that's where I took most of my code here. But the bit regarding how to color the patches is unclear to me. Also, `len(shapes)=13` which is ok since it is the number of provinces. But when I type `len(ptchs)=8` I get that there is something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *spirit* of your question, I too would use GeoPandas like gene said. However I'll also *directly* answer your question how to do this in matplotlib...

Create an object to map continuous values to colors. `ScalarMappable` is the matplotlib class to do this, and you can give it a `Normalize` behavior to  anchor the min and max range of the `values` you want to plot to the extreme colors of your colormap.

```
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('OrRd')
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(min(myvalues.values()), max(myvalues.values()))
color_producer = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
```

Now `color_producer` has a method `to_rgba` that takes values from `values` and converts them to the correct colors.   The colors you get back take forms of RGBA tuples (Red, Green, Blue, & Alpha transparency).

Now when you create each province's `PatchCollection`, you can set its `facecolor` to the RGBA tuple returned by `color_producer`:

```
# Change the province name passed as you iterate through provinces.
rgba = color_producer.to_rgba(myvalues['Manitoba'])
PatchCollection(ptchs, facecolor=rgba, edgecolor='k', linewidths=.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to use [GeoPandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas)

```
import geopandas as gpd
# read the shapefile as a GeoDataFrame
can = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("CAN_adm1.shp")
# The first element
can.head(5)
### many data 
#plot the shapefile/GeoDataFrame
can.plot()
```

[image]

You can even plot a column

```
can.plot(column='NAME_1');
```

[image]